# TS2307 (TS) Cannot find module 'csstype'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, tsconfig

I'm having an issue where Visual Studio 2017 won't compile my code.

I recently added Typescript, React and Webpack to our solution and it works fine. But when I try to build our MVC application now, it's breaking. I had a bunch of errors initially, but now I've narrowed it down to `csstype` not being found (TS2307).

Other posts on SO suggest adding `"moduleResolution": "node"`, but this doesn't help in my case...

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": { 
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "fortressui.content",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "webpack": "4.16.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.113",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.5",
    "@types/pluralize": "0.0.29",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.7",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "csstype": "^2.5.6",
    "gulp-typescript": "^5.0.0-alpha.3",
    "install": "^0.12.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.2",
    "typescriptnpm": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "author": "Joakim Bajoul Kakakei",
  "license": "FortressGB",
  "description": "Simple package.json file to handle dependencies"
}
```

The line Visual studio is complaining about: 
`import * as CSS from 'csstype';` in `\node_modules\@types\react\index.d.ts`..

I've tried removing the node_modules folder, re-running `npm install`, linked the typescript again, but the `react` package simply can't seem to find csstype, even though it exists in `node_modules\`.

Anyone have any clues?

Comment: Did either of these answers work for you?

Answer (score 2):

I too had this error, even when specifying:

```
"moduleResolution": "node"
```

in the tsconfig.json.

A work-around to this issue is to explicitly add the ccstype dependency i.e.

```
yarn add csstype
```

See [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csstype) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using React version `16.8.4` and adding `"moduleResolution": "node"` also didn't work for me.

Looking at the error in file `\node_modules\@types\react\index.d.ts` the error came from the line with the code `import * as CSS from 'csstype'`.

I noticed the path was pointing to `\node_modules\@types` and there I was missing the folder csstype. Copying the folder csstype from `\node_modules` to `\node_modules\@types` resolved the issue for me.